# Check if StructLayout is applied by developer

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

I have a `Type` of a struct. How can I check if the developer has applied a struct layout using the `StructLayoutAttribute`? It is not listed under `Type.CustomAttributes` since there is an `System.RuntimeType.StructLayoutAttribute` that is set in all structs, regardless of the existence of an `StructLayoutAttribute`.

Comment: You'll have to explain why this is important to you.

Comment: My actual goal is to write a custom ASP.Net-Core InputFormatter that will be activated depending on the existence of the attribute to marshal the request bytes to a struct. If not, another formatter will be used. That way no `Content-Type`-header has to be used.

Comment: So you just want your own attribute to specify which formatter should be used.

Comment: I considered it, but I thought using `StructLayoutAttribute` will be easier to handle. But if it's not possible, I'll fall back to it I assume.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a `CustomAttribute` it's a regular `Attribute`.

Which means you can just check `Type.IsLayoutSequential`,`IsExplicitLayout` or `Type.IsAutoLayout`.

EDIT:
Seems the field is exposed directly.
Type.StructLayoutAttribute

Comment: I don't want to get the attribute details. The thing I want to check is if in the struct type definition in the .cs file a `StructLayoutAttribute` is explicitly applied by the developer.

Comment: @BrunoZell without the source .cs file? I would guess that is impossible in a generated assembly - since all structs need a layout

Comment: Yes, without the source file. If it's not possible I really overestimated the power of reflection then, or am I trying to do something non idiomatic here?